# how hash algorithm is considered good

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography

I am reading about hash algorithms in cyber security. Below is text snippet.

> A wonderful property of a secure hash algorithm is that given the
> input, you always get the same output; but given just the output, you
> can’t calculate the input. The strength of such an algorithm can be
> calculated two ways:
>
> 1. The number of tries that would have to be attempted to guarantee finding an input that produces a given hash output. For a well
>    designed hash algorithm, this is assumed to be the size of the output
>    in bits.
> 2. The number of tries that would have to be attempted to have a 50% chance of finding two inputs with exactly the same output. For a
>    well-designed hash algorithm, this is half the size of the output in
>    bits.

My questions on above text are

1. is if I use SHA 256 hash algorithm that generates a 256-bit hash value. In this case from point 1 number of tries that finds an input that produces a given hash output is 256. In this case 256 tries is less which attacker can easily break then how algorithm is considered strength.
2. Another question is for point 2 number of tries for finding two inputs with exactly the same output is half size of output in bits which again 128 which
   attacker can easily tries, then how hash algorithm is  considered well designed?

Kindly help me to understand concept. Thanks for your time

Comment: Not 256.  I'm pretty sure they meant 2^256, i.e. "2 to the power of the output size in bits". A much bigger number.

Comment: OK. Just found the book that's from. It talks about a "secure hash algorithm" as "sort of like an algorithm that encrypts but cannot decrypt." Yikes. The correct term is "[cryptographic hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)". "Secure hash algorithms" are [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms). They are *not* encryption in any sense. I'd try to find another book or something to explain it better. Wikipedia seems to do a good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers for your questions:

1. Your book(?), under the words `size of the output in bits` assumes number of tries is 2^SIZE (^ is power here, not XOR). Thus, for size=256 bit, need make 2^256 tries to find a other source for existing hash. 2^256 is very big value, this is largest, than number of atoms in the known Universe.
2. About generation two sources with same output. This can be performed, using [birthdays paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). In this case, attacker prepares 2^128 `good` messages, and generates 2^128 hashes. Thereafter, he generates sequence of `bad` messages, and for each bad message - he generates hash, and search this new hash within the set of the `good` hashes. Search in the hashtable is O(1). By this way, by a single hashing, attacker can match his single freshly-generated hash versus 2^128 good hashes. As result, he has average number of attempts:

   N = expected_attempts/precomputed_hashes = 2^256/2^128 = 2^128

i.e. it is square root of(2^256), or if count in the bits - need half of the bits of an original hash.

For example, if you can generate any [secp256k1](https://river.com/learn/terms/s/secp256k1/) keypayir, which 160-bit hash of pubkey equals to any Bitcoin address, contains some money, you can steal these money - just generate transaction, contains the signature, verifiable by your pubkey (Bitcoin ownership is hash of the pubkey). Your algorithm to do this - generate keypair, hash of pubkey, and compare hash of your pubkey versus all hashes (UTXOs), published in blockchain. Currently, in the Bitcoin blockchain is < 2^30 unique addresses (hashes). And you need perform ~2^130 attempts to generate collision and steal someone's money. This is practically impossible.